# JavaScript Trouble in WebView playing Video on Jellybean

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, webview

I'm trying to play videos (Not Youtube or Vimeo) in a WebView. I load a HTML file, it runs some Javascript to generate the html5 video tag and the methods to control it. On Kitkat everything works fine, but I'm having trouble supporting Jellybean.

The javascript functions that should be called upon time simply don't get called in Jellybean. I can live with this however. The main problem is when I send commands using mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:video.play();"); the behavior is borked. Sometimes it completely ignores the command, sometimes it catches it, but instead of resuming a paused video like on Kitkat, it restarts the video from the beginning. The fact that it doesn't react the same way everytime makes me wonder if somehow the OS's video player is getting affected, or if I need to force focus on the correct element. The initial play command always works, but after the video starts playing and onShowCustomView() get's called, everything goes bad.

In Kitkat the video simply loads in the WebView but on Jellbean, nothing shows unless I make a custom WebChromeClient and handle the view called in onShowCustomView(). This gives me another view object (in addition to the WebView) and possibly I'm handling it poorly. I've been reading documentation but I still have a weak understanding of why I'm calling onShowCustomView() (I'm perfectly happy to have everything in my lone Webview like on Kitkat), so it's not obvious what I should be doing with the view it gives me. I do know it is the view that actually displays the video however.

I've been banging my head against this wall for days and would appreciate any help or clue.

Here's the code for onShowCustomView()

```
    // Need custom ChromeClient since android < 19
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams webViewSize = mWebView.getLayoutParams();

        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) view;
        SurfaceView focusedChild = (SurfaceView) frameLayout.getFocusedChild();
        frameLayout.removeAllViews();

        mWebView.addView(focusedChild, webViewSize);
```

Comment: i have the same issue playing vimeo video in jellybean, i suspect webview is the culprit it works fine in 4.4+ also i have not tried it with chrome client will try it now

Comment: Yeah, KitKat or higher worked fine. I ended up using reflection to take control of the video playback and created a looping task to check the state every second.